# Jquery passing form values in array to a new page

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I have a dynamic form where I populate values. Once the values are entered, I am able to retrieve them into a jquery array in that same page.

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
                    var myData = [];
                    var rows = $('#customFields').find('tr');
                    rows.find('td input').each(function() {
                        myData.push($(this).val());
                    });
                    alert(myData);
                });
```

However, I want this data to be sent to a new page (let's say processinvoice.asp) with the data hidden so that I can go through the array and write the values into a database and finally display a page saying that it has all be done successfully.

I am not sure how I can pass the array into the new page. Can anyone please give me a hand?

Thanks
Saj

Comment: this might help - http://www.rirath.com/sending-a-javascript-array-via-post-to-asp-classic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hidden form (use CSS to hide a form). Once you have built the `myData` array, set a field in the form with the serialized value of the array. Use jQuery's `submit` on that hidden form to send that array value to that form's `action` page.